# Cannot Read an item from a DynamoDB Table using the DynamoDB Node SDK docClient

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB docClient for Node. I am trying to do a simple read an item call but it throws this error

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

The link that I am following
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.02

Here is my code

```
const id = req.params; //value is 83166ce1-b36b-4074-b586-e2468346eb03
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const params = {
  TableName: 'users',
  Key: {
    'id': id,
  }
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Error fetching user item from DB");
  } else {
    res.status(200).json(data.promoCredits);
  }
});
```

Here is my table configuration
[Table Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ4Hs.png)

My Items

[Items in Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g4vV.png)

I have tried to google but I cannot find an answer to this. Currently I am returning all my users and manually filtering but that is not the optimal solution. Please help.

Hitting my request like this

```
http://localhost:8081/api/user/getPromoCredits/83166ce1-b36b-4074-b586-e2468346eb03
```

my endpoint config is

```
app.get('/api/user/getPromoCredits/:id', user.getUserPromoCredits);
```

Thank you

Comment: where / how is `id` getting defined

Comment: My assumption is that the type of `id` isn’t string.

Comment: You guys are correct, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue where I was not deconstructing my id, and id was of type Object. Based on the two comments above, thank you so much for your help...

Updated to

```
const { id } = req.params;
```